# How to ignore some values while performing aggregation of data using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help to ignore particular values in data while performing data aggregation using mode in pandas. There can be four values [High,Medium,Low,NA] for Columns A1, A2, B1, and B2. 'High' with highest priority and 'Low' being lowest. 'NA' should be ignored.

Here is the scenario,

I have a data as shown below:

```
    date       Type  A1       A2      B1      B2  Price
0   2021-01-01  A    High     Low     Low     NA    20   
1   2021-01-01  A    High     Low     Low     NA    20    
2   2021-01-01  A    Low      High    Low     NA    20   
3   2021-01-01  A    Medium   High    High    NA    20    
4   2021-01-01  B    Low      High    Low     NA    15   
5   2021-01-01  B    Medium   High    High    NA    15
6   2021-01-01  B    Low      Low     Medium  NA    15
6   2021-01-02  A    NA       Low     NA      NA    30    
7   2021-01-02  A    NA       NA      NA      NA    30    
8   2021-01-02  A    NA       NA      NA      NA    30
9   2021-01-02  A    NA       NA      High    NA    30
10  2021-01-02  A    NA       NA      High    NA    30
11  2021-01-02  A    NA       Low     High    NA    30
```

The Output I am getting now is:

```
date           Type  A1       A2      B1    B2  Price
0   2021-01-01  A    High     High    Low   NA  20  
1   2021-01-01  B    Low      High    High  NA  15
2   2021-01-02  A    NA       NA      High  NA  30
```

Expected Output:

```
    date       Type  A1       A2      B1    B2   Price
0   2021-01-01  A    High     High               20  
1   2021-01-01  B    Low      High               15
2   2021-01-02  A             Low                30
```

The columns are related in particular sense. A2 has effect on A1, similarly B2 has effect on B1. I have to perform aggregation individually on each column, but if after performing aggregation on column B2, the output is NA then the cell should be made blank, and also the corresponding cell in B1 should also be made blank, even if it has different aggregation value.

Also, there is another case in column A2 for date 2021-01-02. There are 2 low values and 4 NA values in total. According to mode function, I am getting output as NA, but as I want to ignore NA while aggregation, I need 'Low' as the output value there(as shown in expected output).

If for particular date and type(for example like in column A1, 2021-01-02 of type A) all values are NA, then the output obtained is NA, but I need to ignore NA and obtain blank cell in output, as shown in expected output.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to replace `NA` with `np.nan` which is ignored when calculate `mode`:

```
(df.replace('NA',np.nan)
   .groupby(['date','Type'],, as_index=False)
   .agg(lambda x: x.mode()[0] if x.notna().any() else np.nan)
)
```

Output:

```
         date Type    A1    A2    B1  B2  Price
0  2021-01-01    A  High  High   Low NaN     20
1  2021-01-01    B   Low  High  High NaN     15
2  2021-01-02    A   NaN   Low  High NaN     30
```

Comment: does .any perform a max grouping on the type